# Is there a better way of adding divs dynamically to a existing element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As a part of implementing a emailing app, I am trying to load all the emails from a API and display them to the user. I achieve this by running a forEach loop in which I which create a email element, fill in the relevant details and append it to a container. The container is then appended to a existing view.

Is there a more optimized (faster and cleaner) way to achieve this, by using either vanilla JS or React?

```
fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
    var enc = document.createElement('div');
    enc.className = "enc";
    
    emails.forEach(element => {
      let name = document.createElement('div');
      name.className = "name";
      name.innerHTML = element.sender;

      let subject = document.createElement('div');
      subject.className = "subject";
      subject.innerHTML = element.subject;

      let timestamp = document.createElement('div')
      timestamp.className = "timestamp";
      timestamp.innerHTML = element.timestamp;

      let container = document.createElement('div');
      container.className = "email-container";
      container.appendChild(name);
      container.appendChild(subject);
      container.appendChild(timestamp);

      enc.appendChild(container);
    });
    document.getElementById('emails-view').appendChild(enc)
});
```

Comment: _"Is there a more optimized way..."_ - Please define "optimized". Less memory usage, faster creation of elements, less DOM changes, less method calls, ...

Comment: By optimized I mean faster and cleaner way of dynamically adding elements to DOM.

Comment: Why do you think your approach is slow? And why is this not a _"clear"_ approach?

Comment: I am not sure if this is good approach or if there is a better approach. I am new to JavaScript and I want to know if using innerHTML or react components would make it easier to develop more complicated HTML code.

Comment: cleaner way: use react custom re-usable component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using React, there is no reason to use JS native DOM methods for DOM manipulation. Take advantage of react's jsx syntax.

Here is your example written as a component that loads data on component initialization:

```js
function EmailViewComponent() {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const apiCall = fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(emails => {
        setEmails(emails)
      });
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="emails-view">
      <div className="enc">
        {emails.map(emailItem => (
          <div className="email-container">
            <div className="name">{emailItem.sender}</div>
            <div className="subject">{emailItem.subject}</div>
            <div className="timestamp">{emailItem.timestamp}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this way you will be able to maintain applications way easier and cleaner.

As for the performance, i am not sure which is faster, but i would always go with convenience to write cleaner code as a trade off.

But i am sure that React team pays attention to performance.

Comment: This definitely looks cleaner. Thanks! Also, I am new to react and JavaScript and not familiar with useState and useEffect but did you mean emails.map(), not email.map()?